# javascript external file to html

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make external file to html but it does not work.
the files in the some folder.

please help me, I tried this.

```js
<script>alert("hi");</script>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>

    <script src="/java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>

    </html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Your .js file code doesnt get executed? Also please dont name your file java.js. Java is a totally different language than Javascript.

Comment: try to use <script src="java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: yes does not executed...

Comment: Can you make sure file is in "same" folder or "some" folder?

Comment: in one folder all the files the html and js...

Comment: If file is in the same folder remove / before java.js. `<script src="java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @TahirShahzad still not work...

Comment: <script>alert("hi");</script>

Comment: this is the script <script>alert("hi");</script>

Comment: You don't have to put <script> tag in java.js file

Comment: maybe show us the code inside the java.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working solution for .html and .js file in same folder

```js
// scripts.js 
alert('hello');
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: thx its work now

Comment: @alondavidi Good luck with your journey.